# Pre & Post-Entity Images on Update-Plugin CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I hope somone can help me with a problem I been trying to deal with over some time now. I have a create plugin and a update plugin. For testing purposes my create plugin (Pre-Operation) does a simple calculation and puts the result on a field after save.

My update-plugin works fine when I register it on the pre-operation and change the fields I have my logic for. HOWEVER if I only change one of those fields (or get other fields dirty on the form)I get an error that the key was not present in the dictionary. I have done my research and seen that you do a check between Pre and Post Entity Image to check what fields have been updated and which not. But what I'm confused about is when I do this I need to regrister my update plugin on Post-opertion, which results to my update not working anymore and if I do service.Update(entity) at the end of my code it gives me another error of infinite loop. On my Update plugin I have made sure that I registerd two images (Pre and Post). I would appreciate if someone can advice me, how to do the checks between pre and post images?

Comment: Can you post up the code of the plugin? If my understanding is correct you shouldn't need the pre/post images

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your response, yes the trick was to put an if-statement right on the top of the exceute method (if (context.depth > 1) return;) Appreciate your reply just found it out myself yesterday night :-). –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to see your code. But I can provide short explanation what is going on there.
`service.Update(entity)` call your plugin one more time, because it's another update to entity where your plug in is registered. To avoid this infinite loop you can watch [Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959585.aspx) property. Each new call to plugin will increase value of this property.
If you want to know what properties were changed during update, just look into [InputParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959586.aspx). There will be only updated properties values.
Pre-Entity images are available for Update message, but not for Create (it's impossible to have an image before entity instance was actually created). But Post-Entity image presents in case of both Create and Update messages.
So, if you need to know what properties were changed, check InputParameters. You can do this in Pre-Stage plugin. And value, updates in InputParameters will be stored in database, so you don't need call service.Update.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your response, yes the trick was to put an if-statement right on the top of the exceute method (if (context.depth > 1) return;) Appreciate your reply just found it out myself yesterday night :-).

Comment: Consider marking this answer as accepted as it would seem it provided the answer for you in this case